# Optimize night mode system

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences, android-dark-theme

I created a day/night mode switch system in my app. Currently, I use a PreferenceFragmentCompat + SharedPreference to display and save the switch selection.

This is my code:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);

        PreferencesFragment preferencesFragment = new PreferencesFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.preferences_container, preferencesFragment).commit();

    }


    public static class PreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
        }


        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            if (isAdded()) {
                if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.KEY_PREF_NIGHT_MODE), false)) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                } else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

On top of that, I use the following code in the `OnCreate` method of my main Activity:

```
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        int mode = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.KEY_PREF_NIGHT_MODE), false) ? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES : AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO;
        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() != mode)
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mode);
```

---

The problem is that when I activate the dark mode and I restart the application, it will launch then restart in the `onCreate`. Isn't there a more optimal way to implement this system?

Comment: Create a `Application` class and set the theme there. See my answer here, specifically on Note no. 2 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62081086/9167710

Answer (score 0):

you could create `BaseActivity` where you set the night mode

```
abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO_BATTERY);
    }
}
```

and then extend all your `Activites` from `BaseActivity`

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...
    }
}
```

then your night mode would be set in every activity before `setContentView` and no relaunch would be occured

**UPDATE**

change

```
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
 }
```

to

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

`onStart` is called before view is visible

**UPDATE 2**

here is the singleton to access `SharedPreferences`

```
public class SharedManager {

    private static SharedManager instance;
    private final SharedPreferences preferences;

    private SharedManager() {
        preferences = MyApplication.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static SharedManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (SharedManager.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new SharedManager();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public SharedPreferences getPreferences() {
        return preferences;
    }
}
```

with call `SharedManager.getInstance().getPreferences()` you can get access to Preferences

Comment: I tried to do this but it doesn't work. I try to make sure that the day/night mode chosen in my preference activity is automatically applied without me having anything
to write when I relaunch the application.

Comment: @CodingFR try to call `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in `onStart` instead `onResume`

Comment: but now, I have this error: `E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState`

Comment: then...you should probably use direct SharedPreferences instead of calling from PreferencesFragment to set DayNight before view

Comment: I don't really understand how I can implement this